# Interesting SSRS parameter discovery when using subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have recently been putting together an SSRS report that will run every 15 minutes for the previous 15 minute 'chunk' of time. In essence a very straight forward and simple report that will run via an automated subscription.

I was using Microsoft SQL Server 12 Report Builder Version 3.

I was alerted to an issue with the output csv when my recipient reported being sent blank files, most odd considering the report generated as expected when run manually.

Long story short, it was the expressions I was using to generate the From and To dates. Manual runs produced data, subscription runs did not.

**Original parameters**

**FromDate**

```
dateadd(DateInterval.Second, (second(now()) + 900) * -1, dateadd(Dateinterval.Minute, (minute(now()) mod 15) * -1, now()))
```

**ToDate**

```
dateadd(DateInterval.Second, (second(now()) + 1) * -1, dateadd(Dateinterval.Minute, (minute(now()) mod 15) * -1, now()))
```

**New Parameters**

**FromDate**

```
dateadd(DateInterval.Minute, -15, dateadd(DateInterval.Minute, cint(datediff(DateInterval.Minute,today(),now()) / 15) * 15, today()))
```

**ToDate**

```
dateadd(DateInterval.Second, 899,Parameters!FromDate.Value)
```

Thought I would post this here for two reasons

1. Theories as to why
2. It might help someone in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original parameters take `Now` and subtract the minutes to arrive at a 15-minutes time, then they take the seconds of another `Now` (which is later and could be in the next second or even minute) and subtract that value to arrive at a 0-second time (or a 59-second time). This could already cause a problem when there is a change of seconds between the first and the second `Now`, which isn't very unikely, as on my test system there were 0.59 seconds between the two evaluations of `Now` in the *FromDate* parameter. Also, the `Now` value is more accurate than just a second, and your formula does not respect that. Therefore, if the records you are trying to process in your report happen to have a time of exactly a quarter of an hour, the first parameter is for sure greater (by maybe 0.01 second) and so the record is ignored.

Your formula for the "new parameters" does not depend on the seconds of `Now()` and will always return a time with no fraction of a second, so I guess that that's what makes the difference.

The expression for the *FromDate* could be simplified a little:

```
=Today.AddSeconds(900*(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Today, Now)\15-1))
```

If you do not plan to run the report very short before midnight, there should not be a problem caused by a change of the day during the evaluation of `Today` and `Now`, and you could calculate the second parameter in a similar way, independently from the first one:

```
=Today.AddSeconds(900*(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Today, Now)\15)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang Kais, i'll give that parameter change a try. As with the above comment, we have always had the subscription running at 1 minute past the hour :)

Comment: Ok, thanks,  the I will think about it again... an meanwhile, please forget my comment about the shift to the past, that was complete nonsense, because you correctly subtract the minutes and then the seconds... maybe the problem are the milliseconds, maybe it's that you evaluate the time multiple times. I'll try to find a way to calculate the parameters by requesting the system time only once. What will happen if your data is from within the 1 second between two intervals?

Comment: @VanMacintosh Just updated my answer. The question remains, what happens with the data between for example 00:14:59 and 00:15:00. If your source data is accurate only to the second, this will of course be no issue, but if there are fractions of a second, it will.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, It doesn't go down to the fraction of seconds so this isn't an issue. Thanks for the time you have put into this

Comment: Ok, that's good, so maybe the issue is that your "original parameters" do. If your source data contains a record with a time of exactly 00:15:00 and your `FromDate` parameter evaluates to 00:15:00.01, the source record will probably not be seen on the report.

Answer (score 0):

The original parameter values were being calculated individually which means they would each have slightly different values for `Now()`. I know this is a long shot, but it's a theory. If the subscription job fired off a fraction of a second before a 15 minute interval, it's possible that the `ToDate` returned just before the `FromDate`. This would result in an invalid date range.

With the new expressions, the `ToDate` is referencing the `FromDate` which forces them to be calculated in sequence, not in parallel. Not to mention you're adding to the `FromDate` which also forces the date range to have a consistent length. However, you may still run into a case where you get the same report twice if the `FromDate` is calculated on the wrong side of a 15 minute cutoff.

One way to test/avoid this issue would be to offset the subscription time so that it doesn't actually try to fire at the exact 15 minute cutoffs. For example, you could have it scheduled to go off 1 minute afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the input @StevenWhite, we do have the subscription set up to run at 1 minute past the hour to avoid this :)